# JavaScript Objects - I'm having issues accessing an array of objects properties nested multiple levels & combining them together

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, url, routes

I have an **`array`** of **`objects`** & those **`objects`** contain a property called `children` which are also **`objects`** & they repeat them multiple levels deep(or not).

Basically, **I need to accomplish two things**:

- Get the first level **`path`** property's value & its multiple level within the **`children`** property.
- Concatenating them together to get single **`string`** which will be a route/URL.

For example, following the sample code below, I'll need to get three differents URLs/routes like so:

***`/system-settings1/accounting1/accounting1/etc`***

**`/system-settings2/accounting2/accounting2/etc`**

**`/system-settings3/accounting3/accounting3/etc`**

This is small sample of my **`object`**:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/system-settings1',
    name: 'global-settings1',
    component: 'tabs1',
    children: {
      path: 'accounting1',
      name: 'local-settings1',
      components: 'modals1',
      children: {
        path: 'accounting1',
        name: 'local-settings1',
        components: 'modals1'
        // more children deeply nested(or not)
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/system-settings2',
    name: 'global-settings2',
    component: 'tabs2',
    children: {
      path: 'accounting2',
      name: 'local-settings2',
      components: 'modals2',
      children: {
        path: 'accounting1',
        name: 'local-settings1',
        components: 'modals1'
        // more children deeply nested(or not)
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/system-settings3',
    name: 'global-settings3',
    component: 'tabs3',
    children: {
      path: 'accounting3',
      name: 'local-settings3',
      components: 'modals3',
      children: {
        path: 'accounting1',
        name: 'local-settings1',
        components: 'modals1'
        // more children deeply nested(or not)
      }
    }
  },
]
```

I was able to get the parent's path & its next immediate children's path like so:

```
const routeParentPaths = routes.map(({path}) => path);

const routeChildrenPaths = routes.map(({children}) => children.path);

console.log((routeParentPaths.concat(routeChildrenPaths)));
```

But I need to find a way to access all its children's paths plus I need to find a way to concatenate in order together to form a proper URL per each **`object`**.

You find a code sample **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/o602n81g/).**

Comment: I'm taking this opportunity to advertise my small library for defining routes: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@syndicode/route-maker

PS, it's not clear what array of pathes and why do you want

Comment: Thank you for thanking people here! However, it is not necessary, and it is discouraged in posts, since technical writing is preferred. It is generally best to just accept/upvote/downvote silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can simply keep checking if the `children` key exists and update the object you are checking against. This can get as nested as you would like. I updated one of your routes to allow this to be shown more easily.

Basically

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/system-settings1',
    name: 'global-settings1',
    component: 'tabs1',
    children: {
      path: 'CHILD1accounting1',
      name: 'local-settings1',
      components: 'modals1',
      children: {
        path: 'CHILD2accounting1',
        name: 'local-settings1',
        components: 'modals1'
        // more children deeply nested(or not)
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/system-settings2',
    name: 'global-settings2',
    component: 'tabs2',
    children: {
      path: 'accounting2',
      name: 'local-settings2',
      components: 'modals2',
      children: {
        path: 'accounting1',
        name: 'local-settings1',
        components: 'modals1'
        // more children deeply nested(or not)
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/system-settings3',
    name: 'global-settings3',
    component: 'tabs3',
    children: {
      path: 'accounting3',
      name: 'local-settings3',
      components: 'modals3',
      children: {
        path: 'accounting1',
        name: 'local-settings1',
        components: 'modals1'
        // more children deeply nested(or not)
      }
    }
  },
]



let x = routes.map(route => {
  let path = route.path + "/";
  while(route.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
    route = route.children;
    path += `${route.path}/`
  }
  return path;
});

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a recursive function which takes an object as parameter. [Destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the parameter to get `path` and `children` property. If the nested object doesn't have `children`, return just `path`. Else, recursively call the function on `children` and append it to the current `path`

Then, call this function on each item in the `routes` array using `map`

```
const getPath = ({ path, children }) => children ? `${path}/${getPath(children)}` : path

const output = routes.map(getPath)
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
const 
  routes=[{path:"/system-settings1",name:"global-settings1",component:"tabs1",children:{path:"accounting1",name:"local-settings1",components:"modals1",children:{path:"accounting1",name:"local-settings1",components:"modals1"}}},{path:"/system-settings2",name:"global-settings2",component:"tabs2",children:{path:"accounting2",name:"local-settings2",components:"modals2",children:{path:"accounting1",name:"local-settings1",components:"modals1"}}},{path:"/system-settings3",name:"global-settings3",component:"tabs3",children:{path:"accounting3",name:"local-settings3",components:"modals3",children:{path:"accounting1",name:"local-settings1",components:"modals1"}}},],
  getPath = ({ path, children }) => children ? `${path}/${getPath(children)}` : path,
  output = routes.map(getPath)

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the `routes` array with `Array.map()`, and use a `do...while` loop to construct a url from a nested object.

```js
const getUrl = route => {
  let r = route
  let url = []
  
  do {   
    url.push(r.path)
  } while(r = r.children)

  return url.join('/')
}

const getUrls = routes => routes.map(getUrl)

const routes = [{"path":"/system-settings1","name":"global-settings1","component":"tabs1","children":{"path":"accounting1","name":"local-settings1","components":"modals1","children":{"path":"accounting1","name":"local-settings1","components":"modals1"}}},{"path":"/system-settings2","name":"global-settings2","component":"tabs2","children":{"path":"accounting2","name":"local-settings2","components":"modals2","children":{"path":"accounting1","name":"local-settings1","components":"modals1"}}},{"path":"/system-settings3","name":"global-settings3","component":"tabs3","children":{"path":"accounting3","name":"local-settings3","components":"modals3","children":{"path":"accounting1","name":"local-settings1","components":"modals1"}}}]

const result = getUrls(routes)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create recursive function that will receive data object and previous path and if the object has children call it again.

```js
const routes = [{"path":"/system-settings1","name":"global-settings1","component":"tabs1","children":{"path":"accounting1","name":"local-settings1","components":"modals1","children":{"path":"accounting1","name":"local-settings1","components":"modals1"}}},{"path":"/system-settings2","name":"global-settings2","component":"tabs2","children":{"path":"accounting2","name":"local-settings2","components":"modals2","children":{"path":"accounting1","name":"local-settings1","components":"modals1"}}},{"path":"/system-settings3","name":"global-settings3","component":"tabs3","children":{"path":"accounting3","name":"local-settings3","components":"modals3","children":{"path":"accounting1","name":"local-settings1","components":"modals1"}}}]

function toPaths(data, prev = '') {
  const result = []

  function build(obj, prev = '') {
    prev += (prev ? '/' : '') + obj.path;
    if (obj.children) build(obj.children, prev)
    else result.push(prev)
  }

  data.forEach(e => build(e));
  return result;
}

const paths = toPaths(routes)
console.log(paths)
```